# Show message when UITableView is empty

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` where I show data from a json model. I need when there is no data to show a text.

I tried with the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if datosEventos.events.count == 0{
        let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "No Data"
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        return 0
    } else {
        return datosEventos.events.count
    }
}
```

It works well when there is no data, but when there is data it also shows a few seconds before loading the data into the table.

I have tried with other solutions found here, but the same problem as when loading the table when there is data, the message is displayed for a few seconds, when there is data it should not be displayed.

My function to get the json data is:

```
func GetData()  {

    // Remote JSON to Structed Object
    let url = URL(string: "https://testmysite.com/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    if error == nil {
        do {
          // Decode data to object
           self.datosEventos = try JSONDecoder().decode(EventsFeed.self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()

                print(self.datosEventos)

            }

        } catch let jsonError{
            print("An error occurred: \(jsonError)")
        }
   }

 }.resume()

}
```

[Also try this solution, but the same problem.](https://medium.com/@mtssonmez/handle-empty-tableview-in-swift-4-ios-11-23635d108409)

Image-> example when there is data:

[image: Example when there is data]

Answer (score 2):

As initially the table loads when there is no data and hence this hits

```
if datosEventos.events.count == 0{
    let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
    emptyLabel.text = "No Data"
    emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
```

So either you do it inside the callback after data returns here

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {    // Recommended 
       if datosEventos.events.count == 0 {
       }
       else {}
    }
```

or  do

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if datosEventos.events.count == 0{
        let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "No Data"
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        return 0
    } else { 
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        return datosEventos.events.count
    }

}
```

don't recommend the latter option as it'll show the `no Data` for some time so go with first suggestion

Comment: Define variable `var aaa :Int? `
In DispatchQueue.main.async { self.aaaa = self.datosEventos.events.count}
After in numberOfRowsInSection: `if aaa == 0 {} else { }...` 
Work with this, would it be correct?